Telegram Mini Apps: How do I enable/disable agreement checkbox on app start?
I am creating a Telegram Web App (Mini app) and there's one thing a can't make clear.
When user starts my app he see the disclaimer screen with checkbox like "Allow this bot to write me" (on screenshot). But there's plenty of other apps where no checkboxes like this are shown on start. I can't find anything about it in documentation.
Any ideas?
Thanks.
Nothing was found in docs or Google :(
